# Autoloading fixtures in PHPUnit with package phpunit-provider-autoloader

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, phpunit

I'm using Laravel 8.x and PHP 8.1 and want to autoload fixtures via a data provider in PHPUnit with the following package: [redaxmedia/phpunit-provider-autoloader](https://github.com/redaxmedia/phpunit-provider-autoloader).

The following error occurs when running `vendor/bin/phpunit`:

```sh
There was 1 skipped test:

1) Tests\Feature\ExampleTest::testMethod
Test for Tests\Feature\ExampleTest::testMethod skipped by data provider
PHPUnit\Framework\SkippedTestError: <no message>

OK, but incomplete, skipped, or risky tests!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Skipped: 1.
```

I've done everything as stated in the Readme file:

```php
<?php

namespace Tests;

use PHPUnitProviderAutoloader;

/**
 * TestCaseAbstract
 *
 * @since 4.0.0
 *
 * @package ExampleProject
 * @category Tests
 */

abstract class TestCaseAbstract extends PHPUnitProviderAutoloader\TestCaseAbstract
{
    /**
     * directory of the provider
     *
     * @var string
     */

    protected $_providerDirectory = 'tests' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'provider';

    /**
     * namespace of the testing suite
     *
     * @var string
     */

    protected $_testNamespace = __NAMESPACE__;
}
```

```php
<?php

# tests/provider/ExampleTest_testMethod.php

return
[
    [
        'test'
    ]
];
```

```php
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use Tests\TestCaseAbstract;

/**
 * ExampleTest
 *
 * @since 4.0.0
 *
 * @package ExampleProject
 * @category Tests
 */

class ExampleTest extends TestCaseAbstract
{
    /**
     * testMethod
     *
     * @since 4.0.0
     *
     * @param string $expect
     *
     * @dataProvider providerAutoloader
     */

    public function testMethod(string $expect) : void
    {
        $this->assertEquals($expect, 'test');
    }
}
```

Has anyone had similar issues or can help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I do not see an issue, but remember that the package you are using is extending the PHPUnit TestCase and not Laravel's TestCase...